# How to write Spring Batch with Custom Partition to perform parallel processing

Tags: spring-batch

I have to process records in a batch from database table, such that processing happens in parallel based on group by one database column. Example I have a table T with columns A,B,C. Table has below data.

[image: Table Data]

Now i should process above records in such way that processing happens in 2 parallel threads one thread should process with column A=1 in sequence and other thread should process record with column A=2. Can anyone suggest solution for this?

Comment: How many distinct values do you have in column `A`. This will be the number of partitions. You would need a partitioner that creates a partition for each value in A and make each worker read only rows with the value of A assigned to its parition.